# Installation with Grails and IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, grails

I'm setting up a new project in IntelliJ, but when I run the project in IntelliJ with Grails I get an error that says `"Failed to resolve dependencies" Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information.` I'm not sure what to do next as far as fixing the problem.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin\java" -Dgrails.home=C:\Grails\grails-2.5.3 -Dbase.dir=C:\Users\601279\IdeaProjects "-Dtools.jar=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\lib\tools.jar" -Dgroovy.starter.conf=C:\Grails\grails-2.5.3/conf/groovy-starter.conf -Xmx768M -Xms768M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m -Djline.WindowsTerminal.directConsole=false -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath C:\Grails\grails-2.5.3\lib\org.codehaus.groovy\groovy-all\jars\groovy-all-2.4.4.jar;C:\Grails\grails-2.5.3\dist\grails-bootstrap-2.5.3.jar org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter --main org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner --conf C:\Grails\grails-2.5.3/conf/groovy-starter.conf "create-app gret -plain-output"|Loading Grails 2.5.3
|Configuring classpath
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.aspectj#aspectjweaver;1.8.5

    ==== grailsPlugins: tried

      -- artifact org.aspectj#aspectjweaver;1.8.5!aspectjweaver.jar:

      C:\Users\601279\IdeaProjects\lib\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\Grails\grails-2.5.3\lib\org.aspectj\aspectjweaver\ivy-1.8.5.xml

      -- artifact org.aspectj#aspectjweaver;1.8.5!aspectjweaver.jar:

      C:\Grails\grails-2.5.3\lib\org.aspectj\aspectjweaver\jars\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar

      C:\Grails\grails-2.5.3\lib\org.aspectj\aspectjweaver\bundles\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\Grails\grails-2.5.3\dist\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.pom

      -- artifact org.aspectj#aspectjweaver;1.8.5!aspectjweaver.jar:

      C:\Grails\grails-2.5.3\dist\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\Users\601279\.grails\2.5.3\cached-installed-plugins\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.xml

      -- artifact org.aspectj#aspectjweaver;1.8.5!aspectjweaver.jar:

      C:\Users\601279\.grails\2.5.3\cached-installed-plugins\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\Grails\grails-2.5.3\plugins\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.pom

      -- artifact org.aspectj#aspectjweaver;1.8.5!aspectjweaver.jar:

      C:\Grails\grails-2.5.3\plugins\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.aspectj#aspectjweaver;1.8.5: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.5

 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.aspectj#aspectjweaver;1.8.5

    ==== grailsPlugins: tried

      -- artifact org.aspectj#aspectjweaver;1.8.5!aspectjweaver.jar:

      C:\Users\601279\IdeaProjects\lib\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\Grails\grails-2.5.3\lib\org.aspectj\aspectjweaver\ivy-1.8.5.xml

      -- artifact org.aspectj#aspectjweaver;1.8.5!aspectjweaver.jar:

      C:\Grails\grails-2.5.3\lib\org.aspectj\aspectjweaver\jars\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar

      C:\Grails\grails-2.5.3\lib\org.aspectj\aspectjweaver\bundles\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\Grails\grails-2.5.3\dist\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.pom

      -- artifact org.aspectj#aspectjweaver;1.8.5!aspectjweaver.jar:

      C:\Grails\grails-2.5.3\dist\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\Users\601279\.grails\2.5.3\cached-installed-plugins\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.xml

      -- artifact org.aspectj#aspectjweaver;1.8.5!aspectjweaver.jar:

      C:\Users\601279\.grails\2.5.3\cached-installed-plugins\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\Grails\grails-2.5.3\plugins\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.pom

      -- artifact org.aspectj#aspectjweaver;1.8.5!aspectjweaver.jar:

      C:\Grails\grails-2.5.3\plugins\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.aspectj#aspectjweaver;1.8.5: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.5

 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.aspectj#aspectjweaver;1.8.5

    ==== grailsPlugins: tried

      -- artifact org.aspectj#aspectjweaver;1.8.5!aspectjweaver.jar:

      C:\Users\601279\IdeaProjects\lib\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\Grails\grails-2.5.3\lib\org.aspectj\aspectjweaver\ivy-1.8.5.xml

      -- artifact org.aspectj#aspectjweaver;1.8.5!aspectjweaver.jar:

      C:\Grails\grails-2.5.3\lib\org.aspectj\aspectjweaver\jars\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar

      C:\Grails\grails-2.5.3\lib\org.aspectj\aspectjweaver\bundles\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\Grails\grails-2.5.3\dist\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.pom

      -- artifact org.aspectj#aspectjweaver;1.8.5!aspectjweaver.jar:

      C:\Grails\grails-2.5.3\dist\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\Users\601279\.grails\2.5.3\cached-installed-plugins\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.xml

      -- artifact org.aspectj#aspectjweaver;1.8.5!aspectjweaver.jar:

      C:\Users\601279\.grails\2.5.3\cached-installed-plugins\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\Grails\grails-2.5.3\plugins\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.pom

      -- artifact org.aspectj#aspectjweaver;1.8.5!aspectjweaver.jar:

      C:\Grails\grails-2.5.3\plugins\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.aspectj#aspectjweaver;1.8.5: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.5

 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.aspectj#aspectjweaver;1.8.5

    ==== grailsPlugins: tried

      -- artifact org.aspectj#aspectjweaver;1.8.5!aspectjweaver.jar:

      C:\Users\601279\IdeaProjects\lib\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\Grails\grails-2.5.3\lib\org.aspectj\aspectjweaver\ivy-1.8.5.xml

      -- artifact org.aspectj#aspectjweaver;1.8.5!aspectjweaver.jar:

      C:\Grails\grails-2.5.3\lib\org.aspectj\aspectjweaver\jars\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar

      C:\Grails\grails-2.5.3\lib\org.aspectj\aspectjweaver\bundles\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\Grails\grails-2.5.3\dist\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.pom

      -- artifact org.aspectj#aspectjweaver;1.8.5!aspectjweaver.jar:

      C:\Grails\grails-2.5.3\dist\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\Users\601279\.grails\2.5.3\cached-installed-plugins\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.xml

      -- artifact org.aspectj#aspectjweaver;1.8.5!aspectjweaver.jar:

      C:\Users\601279\.grails\2.5.3\cached-installed-plugins\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\Grails\grails-2.5.3\plugins\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.pom

      -- artifact org.aspectj#aspectjweaver;1.8.5!aspectjweaver.jar:

      C:\Grails\grails-2.5.3\plugins\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.aspectj#aspectjweaver;1.8.5: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.5

 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.5

|Run 'grails dependency-report' for further information.
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the bug with Grails `v2.5.3` and already reported.

This is already included and fixed on the `2.5.x` branch.

Please check [this](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9670) and [this](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9450)

So you need to upgrade your grails version

Hope this will helps you